# VB.NET - Switch Network SQL Server 2008 R2 Database to a mobile SQL Server CE *.sdf File

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, export, sql-server-ce

I have developed a VB.NET program using a strongly typed dataset. This dataset has its connection to a SQL Server 2008 R2. The software should now be additionally used offline. The database should be exported to a *.sdf database. If no connection to the SQL server is produced, the software have to try to connect to the *.sdf database.

I would like to achieve:
1. Export the data in the SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a local *.sdf file.
2. This *.sdf file has to work as an alternate connection string in the strongly typed dataset.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SQL Server Compact Toolbox can help you with question 1. http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html

Comment: Hello, I tried your toolbox before you post here. The result of your toolbox were approx. 50 *.sdf files: Database_1.sdf, Database_2.sdf, ... - SQL Server Management Studio was not able to read this.

Comment: See the blog post, there is no reference to SSMS (using command line only)

Comment: I solved it with a batch: 
d:
cd D:\SQL_Server DB Export
DEL Database.sdf
Export2sqlce "Data Source=SQL_Server;Initial Catalog=dbXY;Integrated Security=True" AW.sqlce
sqlcecmd -d "Data Source=D:\SQL_Server DB Export\Database.sdf" -e create
FOR /F "delims=*" %%f IN ('dir /b /s *.sqlce') do sqlcecmd -d "Data Source=Database.sdf" -i "%%f"
DEL *.sqlce

Comment: After 2 hours I get:  Error Code: 80004005
 Message   : Die Größe der Datenbankdatei überschreitet das konfigurierte Maximu
m. Diese Einstellung wird erst bei der ersten gleichzeitigen Datenbankverbindung
 wirksam. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 257 ]
 Minor Err.: 25104
 Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
 Num. Par. : 257

Comment: Change your connection strings to the sdf file as follows:
-d "Data Source=D:\SQL_Server DB Export\Database.sdf;Max Database Size=4000"
(Default max db size is 256 MB)